# Fazer o ID seguir em sequência sem usar auto incremento

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estou com um problema de banco. Ao cadastrar um usuário o ID é dado como 0. Tento usar o Auto Incremento, mas quando eu ativo essa opção, os outros cadastros param de funcionar.

Comment: No code, no help.

Comment: Em qual não consegue? No phpmyadmin ou num código php?

Comment: É comum nestes casos, criar uma função que recupera o último ID e acrescenta + 1

Answer (score 0):

Se eu bem entendi, você quer por `PHP`, sendo assim pode fazer desta forma.

Primeiro faça um `SELECT` de todos os usuários antes de inserir, utilize um código similar a este

```
$este=mysqli_query($variavel_db, "SELECT * FROM tabela order by id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
```

Com o código acima irá buscar o ultimo inserido. Se não existir, basta uma pequena condição que faça inserir com `id = 1`, ou seja, veja o código resumido.

```
$este=mysqli_query($variavel_db, "SELECT * FROM tabela order by id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
if(mysqli_num_rows($este) == 0){
   $insert=mysqli_query($variavel_db, "INSERT INTO tabela (id, valor1, valor2, etc) VALUES (1, valor1, valor2, etc)");
}else{
   $mos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($este);
   $plus=$mos['id']+1;
   $insert=mysqli_query($variavel_db, "INSERT INTO tabela (id, valor1, valor2, etc) VALUES ('$plus', 'valor1', 'valor2', etc)");
}
```